# OfBiz launches but browser cannot view any of the webpages on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, windows, gradle, browser, ofbiz

System: Windows 10 Enterprise.
OfBiz version: 18.12.08
Database: Postgresql 15.3 (demo data loaded.)
Gradle: 8.3
JDK: 17.0.8.101

This is my first time using OfBiz. As far as I can tell, I am able to build and launch, after executing ./gradlew ofbiz.
However when I attempt to browse any of the OfBiz web components, I get no response except for https://localhost:10523/webtools.

From the log, I cannot yet tell what I have done wrong or not done that is currently missing from my setup.

I have tried to browse and also verify connection using Curl, but without success.

D:\01Download>curl https://localhost:50746/webtools
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 50746 after 2249 ms: Couldn't connect to server

D:\01Download>curl https://localhost:10523/webtools
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid

D:\01Download>curl https://localhost:8443/webtools
curl: (28) SSL/TLS connection timeout
(Also, browser reporting - localhost refused to connect for this port.)

I was expecting to be able to browse the various OfBiz web components.
Thank you.

Additional information from the log:

INFO: No global web.xml found
(This entry occurs once in the log.)

INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
(There are several instances of this entry in the log.)

How do I resolve these issues?
Thanks.

[Adding build scan report uploaded to Gradle](https://scans.gradle.com/s/mo2cgkcjg3kck)
Is there anything in this report that might highlight what I have done wrong or missed?

Started today at 074746 EAT, finished today at 074924 EAT
Gradle 8-3, Gradle Enterprise plugin 3-14-1

0 failures This build did not contain any failures.

7 build deprecations
The org gradle api plugins Convention type has been deprecated. 3 usages
The org gradle api plugins JavaPluginConvention type has been deprecated.   2 usages
The RepositoryHandler jcenter method has been deprecated.   1 usage
The org gradle api plugins ApplicationPluginConvention type has been deprecated.    1 usage

16 tasks executed in 1 project in 1m 37s
compileJava 48.418s
test    11.642s
distZip 10.184s
compileGroovy   6.331s
distTar 4.665s
processResources    4.280s

Explore timeline
1m 37s total build time
Initialization and configuration    5.808s
Execution   1m 31.542s
Explore performance

59 tests executed in 17 test classes taking 12s
GetLocaleListTests frenchLocaleName 2.472s
DelegatorUnitTests delegatorCreationUsingFactoryGetDelegator    1.233s
UtilCodecTests testCheckStringForHtmlStrictNone 1.106s
EntitySaxReaderTests constructorWithTimeout 0.730s
DelegatorUnitTests delegatorCreationUsingConstructorFailsIfConfigurationIsMissing   0.678s
DelegatorUnitTests delegatorCreationUsingFactoryGetInstance 0.648s
Explore tests

53 projects
ofbiz 4
applications 12
framework 14
plugins 17
themes 5
Explore projects

593 dependencies resolved in 1 project across 6 configurations from 6 repositories
runtimeClasspath    1.078s
testRuntimeClasspath    0.071s
compileClasspath    0.069s
testCompileClasspath    0.046s
annotationProcessor 0.000s
testAnnotationProcessor 0.000s
Explore dependencies

26 build dependencies resolved in 1 project across 2 configurations from 3 repositories
build gradle    0.021s
settings gradle 0.001s
Explore build dependencies

22 plugins in 53 projects
org gradle build-init   53 usages
org gradle help-tasks   53 usages
org gradle wrapper  53 usages
at bxm svntools 1 usage
com gradle enterprise   1 usage
org asciidoctor gradle.asciidoctor  1 usage
Explore plugins

0 custom values This build did not contain any custom values.

Switches
Background build scan publication On
Build output capturing On
Daemon On
File system watching On
Test output capturing On
Build Cache Off
Configuration Cache Off
Configure on demand Off
Continue on failure Off
Continuous Off
Dry run Off
Offline Off
Parallel Off
Re-run tasks Off
Refresh dependencies Off
Task inputs file capturing Off

Infrastructure
Operating system Windows 10 10 amd64
CPU cores 8 cores
Max Gradle workers 8 workers
Java runtime Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17.0.8.1-1
Java VM Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.8.1-1 mixed mode, sharing
Max JVM memory heap size 512 MiB
Locale English United States
Default charset windows-1252

Comment: Added report from Build scan on gradle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFBiz 18.12.08 is not supposed to work with Gradle 8.3 and JDK 17 but Gradle 5.0 and JDK 11.

Please try that.

Also don't forget to preferably use init-gradle-wrapper.bat

Comment: Thank you, @JacquesLeRoux. I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

System Requirements:

- trunk requires Java SDK 11 (there is ongoing work to move to Java SDK 17, see issue OFBIZ-12722)
- 18.12 requires Java SDK 8
- 17.12 requires Java SDK 8
- 16.11 requires Java SDK 8

Setup :

- Load OFBiz demo data in the embedded Apache Derby database running
  "gradlew loadAll" on Windows or "./gradlew loadAll" on Linux/Unix/OSX
- Start OFBiz with embedded Tomcat by going into the ofbiz directory
  and then running Windows: "gradlew ofbiz" or "startofbiz.bat" (or
  even "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar build\libs\ofbiz.jar")
  Linux/Unix/OSX: "./gradlew ofbiz" or "./startofbiz.sh" (or even
  "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar build/libs/ofbiz.jar").

Open a browser and go to
https://localhost:8443/webtools